# Installing bluetooth manager without a keyboard

Tags: raspberrypi

I'm trying to connect a non-dongle bluetooth keyboard to a rasberry pi but I don't have a regular keyboard to set it up. Just a mouse.

I have a script to install the bluetooth manager which i can transfer over from a thumb drive but no way to execute it. Is there a script to execute commands?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a on screen keyboard. Just look here into the official [documentation:](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-osk.html.en)

Instead of typing "settings" you have to search for the entry manually, which should not be a problem.

If you want to run a script (.sh), it's best to copy to your home folder. Then run a terminal and type

```
chmod +x yourscript.sh
./yourscript.sh
```

First line will make the file executable, which is an addition security barrier so you don't run downloaded files accidently. Second line will run the script.